# Linq string compare error

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

Scenario:

```
 const string srchFormatter = "{0} {1} {2}";

 var result = from c in db.ContactsDumps1s
                     where string.Format(srchFormatter, c.FirstName, c.MiddleName, c.LastName).Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim())
                     select new { c.FirstName, c.MiddleName, c.LastName };
```

Error:

> Method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object)' has no supported translation to SQL.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Method 'System.String
>   Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object, System.Object)'
>   has no supported translation to SQL.

Can anybody please let me know why am I not able to search in this manner & any alternatives for this search?

This is what I plan to achieve :

```
select FirstName, MiddleName, LastName 
from ContactsDumps1 
where FirstName+MiddleName+LastName like '%Search_String%'
```

by using LINQ.

Comment: Don't over-emphasize your entire question with **bold letters** - that's totally unncessary and contraproductive.

Comment: @marc_s for better visibility! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're doing a LINQ-to-SQL query, since your DB context is tied to a database connection.  In doing this, you're issuing a query to your database.  Think about the query that you're constructing:

```
from c in db.ContactsDumps1s
                     where string.Format(srchFormatter, c.FirstName, c.MiddleName, c.LastName).Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim())
                     select new { c.FirstName, c.MiddleName, c.LastName };
```

Which probably translates to something like:

```
SELECT FN, MN, LN
FROM ContactsDumps1s
WHERE 'FN FN FN' Contains SomeTextValue
```

That doesn't really translate well.  I think what you're trying to do is a LIKE - where `FirstName Starts With SomeTextValue`.

So you may want to try:

```
    from c in db.ContactsDumps1s
    where c.FirstName.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.Trim()) ||
          c.MiddleName.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.Trim()) ||
          c.LastName.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.Trim())
    select new { c.FirstName, c.MiddleName, c.LastName };
```

I may not understand what you're exactly trying to do, but hopefully this helps.  Let me know if I'm missing something and I'll clarify my answer.

**UPDATE**: I updated my suggested LINQ statement to search FirstName, MiddleName or LastName for the text in txtSearch.

**UPDATE #2**: I noticed your updated question and what you're looking to do.  Here's an approach that may work for you:

```
from c in db.ContactsDumps1s
where (c.FirstName + " " + c.MiddleName + " " + c.LastName).StartsWith(txtSearch.Text.Trim())
select new { c.FirstName, c.MiddleName, c.LastName };
```

Using LINQPad, I did something similar and the generated SQL from it is:

```
SELECT [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[MiddleName], [t0].[LastName]
FROM [SalesLT].[Customer] AS [t0]
WHERE (([t0].[FirstName] + @p0) + ([t0].[MiddleName] + @p0) + [t0].[LastName]) LIKE @p1
```

That roughly translates to what you want to do.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This last query searches only for the first name, I am looking for Middle & Last one too

Comment: Updated my suggested answer by search FirstName, MiddleName or LastName.

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like this if you looking for lines that contain txtSearch.Text in any of the fields

```
var result = from c in db.ContactsDumps1s
where c.FirstName.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim()) ||
c.MiddleName.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim()) || 
c.LastName.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim())
select new { c.FirstName, c.MiddleName, c.LastName };
```

This is code to compare db.ContactsDumps1s with all three fields combined. Be careful it is slow.

```
var result = (from c in db.ContactsDumps1s
    select new { c.FirstName, c.MiddleName, c.LastName, 
    Combined = c.FirstName + c.LastName + c.MiddleName})
    .Where(u => u.Combined.Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim())).ToArray();
```

First options looks better to me for site search. Second option will require user to know all 3 fields to find somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Why not?

```
var result = from c in db.ContactsDumps1s
             where (c.FirstName + " " + c.MiddleName + " " + c.LastName)
                 .Contains(txtSearch.Text.Trim())
             select new { c.FirstName, c.MiddleName, c.LastName };
```